# How do I record a stream from an HDHomeRun Connect DUO via VLC?

Tags: vlc, tv-tuner

I have an HDHomeRun Connect DUO hooked up to an aerial mast to watch over the air television.  I'm trying to record TV shows in a more lightweight fashion than making an all-up installation of MythTV.  VLC has [documentation on working with streams](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/) but it is not quite complete.

The minimum working example of the CLI invocation of VLC that I am using is this:

```
/usr/bin/cvlc --network-caching=6666 --postproc-q=1 --sout-transcode-deinterlace --sout-transcode-threads=4 -vvv --no-repeat --no-loop http://192.168.0.27:5004/auto/v35.1 --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=4096,acodec=mp3,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2}:std{access="file",mux="mp4",dst="CBSTest.mp4"}' --stop-time=60 vlc://quit
```

In this example I am invoking the headless version of VLC, using a nominal amount of caching due to the latency on my network, post-processing at the lowest intensity level, deinterlacing, using four threads to transcode, not looping or repeating, pull the stream from the box for ATSC channel 35.1, and transcode it to a basic MP4 container named CBSTest.mp4 with the run lasting 60 seconds and VLC then quitting.

During the test run, some errors were kicked back including:

```
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] MPEG motion vector out of boundary (-8 480)
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] concealing 120 DC, 120 AC, 120 MV errors in P frame
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] 00 motion_type at 108 21
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] Invalid mb type in P-frame at 23 22
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] concealing 181 DC, 181 AC, 181 MV errors in P frame
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] 00 motion_type at 12 39
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f653c027380] concealing 120 DC, 120 AC, 120 MV errors in P frame
[00007f65480063b0] ts demux warning: discontinuity received 0xf instead of 0xe (pid=49)
```

Unless I am getting a lousy over the air signal are there any other settings to fiddle with for caching to prevent such problems?